# How to estimate theta value in FOPDT equation using gekko?

Tags: python, gekko

I'm trying to use GEKKO to fit to a certain dataset, using the FOPDT Optimization Method to estimate k, tau and theta.

I saw the example using odeint on https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/FirstOrderOptimization and tried to do the same thing with GEKKO, but I can't use the value of theta in the equation.

I saw this question [where should the delay call be placed inside a gekko code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58287318/where-should-the-delay-call-be-placed-inside-a-gekko-code) and the docs https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/TimeDelay, but in this case I wanted to estimate the value of theta and not use the initial guess value. I tried to use gekko's delay, but I get an error that it only works if the delay is an int value (and not a gekko FV).
I also tried to use time directly in the equation, but I can't figure out how to place x(t-theta) in there, since I can't do that syntax with gekko variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import plotly.express as px 

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=',',header=0,index_col=0)

xm1 = data['x']
ym1 = data['y']
xm = xm1.to_numpy()
ym = ym1.to_numpy()

xm_r = len(xm)
tm = np.linspace(0,xm_r-1,xm_r)

m = GEKKO()
m.options.IMODE=5
m.time = tm

k = m.FV()
k.STATUS=1
tau = m.FV()
tau.STATUS=1
theta = m.FV()
theta.STATUS=1

x = m.Param(value=xm)
y = m.CV()
y.FSTATUS = 1
yObj = m.Param(value=ym)

xtheta = m.Var()
m.delay(x,xtheta,theta)

m.Equation(y.dt()==(-y + k * xtheta)/tau)
m.Minimize((y-yObj)**2)
m.options.EV_TYPE=2

m.solve(disp=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some strategies for implementing variable time-delay in a model such as when an optimizer adjusts the time delay in a First Order Plus Dead Time (FOPDT) model.

- Create a cubic spline (continuous approximation) of the relationship between time `t` and the input `u`. This allows a fractional time delay that is not restricted to an integer multiple of the sample interval.
- Create `time` as a variable with derivative equal to 1.
- Define `tc` with an equation `tc==time-theta` to get the time shifted value. This will lookup the spline `uc` value that corresponds to this `tc` value.

[image: FOPDT optimization]

You can also [fit the FOPDT model](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DataSimulation) to data with Excel or other tools.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
url = 'http://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/tclab_siso_data.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
t = data['time'].values
u = data['voltage'].values
y = data['temperature'].values

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = t; time = m.Var(0); m.Equation(time.dt()==1)

K = m.FV(lb=0,ub=1);      K.STATUS=1
tau = m.FV(lb=1,ub=300);  tau.STATUS=1
theta = m.FV(lb=2,ub=30); theta.STATUS=1

# create cubic spline with t versus u
uc = m.Var(u); tc = m.Var(t); m.Equation(tc==time-theta)
m.cspline(tc,uc,t,u,bound_x=False)

ym = m.Param(y)
yp = m.Var(y); m.Equation(tau*yp.dt()+(yp-y[0])==K*(uc-u[0]))

m.Minimize((yp-ym)**2)

m.options.IMODE=5
m.solve()

print('K: ', K.value[0])
print('tau: ',  tau.value[0])
print('theta: ', theta.value[0])

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,u)
plt.legend([r'$V_1$ (mV)'])
plt.ylabel('MV Voltage (mV)')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t,yp)
plt.legend([r'$T_{1meas}$',r'$T_{1pred}$'])
plt.ylabel('CV Temp (degF)')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.savefig('sysid.png')
plt.show()
```

```
K:  0.25489655932
tau:  229.06377617
theta:  2.0
```

Another way to approach this is to estimate a [higher-order ARX model](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/ARXTimeSeries) and then determine the statistical significance of the `beta` terms. Here is an example of using the Gekko `sysid` function.

[image: System Identification]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data and parse into columns
url = 'http://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/tclab_siso_data.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
t = data['time']
u = data['voltage']
y = data['temperature']

# generate time-series model
m = GEKKO()

# system identification
na = 5 # output coefficients
nb = 5 # input coefficients
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb,pred='meas')

print('alpha: ', p['a'])
print('beta: ',  p['b'])
print('gamma: ', p['c'])

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,u)
plt.legend([r'$V_1$ (mV)'])
plt.ylabel('MV Voltage (mV)')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t,yp)
plt.legend([r'$T_{1meas}$',r'$T_{1pred}$'])
plt.ylabel('CV Temp (degF)')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.savefig('sysid.png')
plt.show()
```

With results:

```
alpha:  [[0.525143  ]
 [0.19284469]
 [0.08177381]
 [0.06152181]
 [0.12918898]]
beta:  [[[-8.51804876e-05]
  [ 5.88425202e-04]
  [ 1.99205676e-03]
  [-2.81456773e-03]
  [ 2.38110003e-03]]]
gamma:  [0.75189199]
```

The first two `beta` terms are nearly zero but they can also be left in the model for a higher-order representation of the system.

Comment: In the Gekko parameter estimation for theta portion of your answer, why do you have (yp-y[0]) and (uc-u[0]) in the equation versus just yp and uc?

Comment: Deviation variables are required to avoid the solution of yp = up at steady state. It is a non-zero intercept such as yp = up + c but in deviation variable form where u[0] and y[0] are steady state conditions or another "starting" point.

Comment: Understood. Why does the equation have d(yp)/dt instead of d(yp-y[0])/dt? I understand that d(yp-y[0])/dt would be equal to d(yp)/dt if y[0] is in fact steady state, but if the system is not at steady state at time 0 then how can that be incorporated? Would tau*(yp.dt-y0.dt) work (with y0=m.Var(y[0])? Let me know if I should ask a new question.

Comment: The `y[0]` is a constant so `dy[0]/dt=0` and that term cancels. There is more information on this here: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/ModelLinearization